# What's wrong with my spatial SQL queries?

Tags: qgis, sql

I have 3 tables within the `sample.gpkg`, descirbes as following:

```
sample.gpkg
    
--  parcel [polygon]
    ----------------
    fields:
        - landuseType
        - landuseZoning
        - parcelSerialNumber
    
--  building [point]
    ----------------
    fields:
        - name
        - longitude
        - latitude
    
--  capacity [no-geometry] (import from txt)
    ---------------------------------------
    fields:
        - location
        - capacity
```

The **capacity.location** can be joined onto **building.name**, it's just identical value with different field name. The goal is to `Create a new parcel field that contains the remaining capacity above 0 within building buffered by 500 metres.`(Since the buffered area might overlap, I want the overlapped area's capacity to be summed up)

This is the query I came up with, yet it never completes.
Where did it go wrong?

```sql
SELECT
  prcl.*
  sum(j.remain) as remain_sum    --sum up the `remain` if overlapped...? not sure if correct

FROM 
  parcel as prcl,
  (
    SELECT 
      b.geom, 
      b.name, 
      cap.remain_202309 as remain
    FROM 
      building as b
    LEFT JOIN
      capacity as cap
    ON
      b.name = cap.location
  ) as j    

WHERE
  st_within(prcl.geom, st_buffer(j.geom, 500))    --buffer by 500
  AND
  remain_sum > 0
```

p.s. I ran the query within QGIS DB manager.

Comment: How many parcels and points are there? Virtual layers are often slow. Do you have PostgreSQL+PostGIS?

Comment: Sorry I don't(does it not come with qgis? I'm new to the concept using sql in QGIS). the parcel was around 10k and points around 300. Yet this is already a slight portion of data dragged out from original data(around 100 times more rows)

Comment: At least, you need a `group by` clause in your main `select`, since you are using a `sum()` clause, which is an aggregate function.

Comment: PostgreSQL and PostGIS does not come with QGIS, but it is open source so you can just install it. It intergrates very well with QGIS using the DB Manager. It is a proper database, alot faster than Virtual Layers. See: https://postgis.net/

Comment: Which is the srid of your data. Take into account that buffer, uses the units of the srid. And seccond never use st_within + st_buffer, use st_dwithin instead https://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2021/05/indexes-and-queries.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with QGIS, but as with any database, try following techniques and optimizations to make it faster

1. find out what parts of the query are slow. I expect spatial join to be slow, but do execute sub-queries, and see how they perform.
2. e.g. run just the first join to make sure it is fast enough.
3. check if computing `ST_Buffer` is expensive - just compute ST_Buffer on all buildings. Even better - add a new column with precomputed buffer around building, use it in the query instead of computing ST_Buffer each time (this also helps with index in next step).
4. create indices.

QGIS seem to support spatial indices, create them on both tables,  prcl.geom and the buffer column from step 3.

https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/spatial_databases/spatial_queries.html#spatial-indexes